# Comparing an array value to another array with PHP

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I currently have a table of file names. These file names are populated by looping through a directory and outputting the results (using php). Once these files are processed they are added to a database. After being added to the database the user is then able to click a link and it will update a field in the database to make it "available". The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to figure out whether or not each file is "available", and if a particular file has been made available, display another column in the table stating it has been sent. I'm using codeigniter. My model is returning all of the filenames in the database that are available but I can't seem to compare them in the table and adjust it accordingly.

```
  print_r($avail); // returns Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [filename] => example1 ) ) from the database

  Filename    ||    Send (Link)     || File is sent
  example1    ||    Send the file   ||  Not Sent
  example2    ||    Send the file   ||  Not Sent
```

The column "file is sent" should show the word "sent" for example1 because it has been returned from the database.

How do I compare the returned values? bearing in mind that an array is used to actually get the filenames.

To put it into the table I have tried something like:

```
 if (in_array($avail,$extensionDownload)) {
               print("<td>" . "Sent" . "</td>");
          } else {
               print("<td>" . "Not Sent" . "</td>");
           }
```

`$extensionDownload` is the files itself. It returns :

`Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => .DS_Store [3] => example1 [4] => example2 )`

but I've trimmed it to only return the filenames and not the initial directories.

Apologies if this post sounds confusing but the process itself is quiet complex. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put some code, where's ``$avail`` coming from? And what you're using in your foreach ?

Comment: $avail is coming from my model, its pulling the values that are "available" from the database I just need to compare them to the values in $extensionDownload. If the values match then the column "file is sent" in the table should say "sent" for that particular file.

Comment: if your ``$avail`` is an array of objects then your example have an issue as ``in_array` takes a $needle -> single var then a $haystack -> array. without full example of what you're doing that's the most of what I can provide.

Comment: I'm just basically looking to figure out how to compare an array value against another array , if it exists in that array I want to change the css of something and output "sent" in the table , I appreciate your help!